# how to use javascript in php and dealing with a file

Tags: javascript, php, file

this is part of my code , i need to read from a file , and I need to make some operation to the lines(split the string) then print the info in a table
so i need to use java script to deal with the Strings , but my code is doesn't work because of the script tag ()
so , how can i use javascript in php and dealing with the file on the same time ?

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("scores.txt", "r");
    echo "<script>";
    echo "<table border=1 ><tr><th> Home Team </th><th> Home Team Score </th> <th> Away Team Score </th> <th> Away Team </th></tr>";
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
        $str = fgets($myfile);
    echo " var temp = $str.split(':');";
    echo "<tr> <td> temp[0] </td> <td> temp[2] </td><td> temp[3] </td> <td> temp[1]</td></tr>";
     }
    echo "</table></script>";
    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
```

Comment: you can't use `<table>` inside a `<script>` tag

Comment: this should be done in php, not in js! - you're mixing it up anyway.

Comment: ahaa , that's was the problem ? then can you tell me how can i deal with it ?

Comment: Are you doing JS templating? Or what is the reason behind using the script tag?

Comment: You are mixing and maching 2 different programming languages. `$temp = explode( ':' , $str)`, then use `$temp[0]` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing php and javascript. That won't work.
But you don't need Javascript here.
If the file-operations are correct this should work:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("scores.txt", "r");

echo "<table border=1 ><tr><th> Home Team </th><th> Home Team Score </th> <th> Away Team Score </th> <th> Away Team </th></tr>";
while(!feof($myfile)) {
    $str = fgets($myfile);
    $temp = explode(':', $str);
    echo "<tr><td>". $temp[0] ."</td><td>". $temp[2] ."</td><td>". temp[3] ."</td><td>". temp[1] ."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: <strike>Please delete the `var` in front of $tmp</strike> Never mind :)

Comment: EDIT: had left "var" in there, now gone... @MujnoiGyulaTamas yeah, just noticed it...